# Request for member which is of non-class

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've got a C++ class I want to use which has all the code in the header file, rather than the CPP file. I'm trying to call it from an objective-C file which inherits a UIViewController class. I've renamed the file to .mm and imported the header file for the C++ file. When I compile, I keep getting a compile-time error when I try and access a method from the C++ class saying `Request for member '<method>' in '<objectName>' which is of non-class type '<C++ class name>'`. I did a search and it seemed that the header was usually the issue, but I've included the header in my file. What else could it be? (I can include generic code if required, but the I'm not sure if I'm allowed to show the actual code since it belongs to a third party).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a C++ coder, so this was probably an obvious mistake, but if anyone else comes across a similar problem, I simply changed my code from:

```
myObject.method();
```

to

```
myObject->method();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in the declaration of the object that gives you the error, not in the header file. Sometimes the problem is hard to spot, you'll have to share some code if you can't figure it out by yourself.

Comment: I was just coding a generic version to post here and managed to find the fix. Thanks anyway!