# Pointer to struct, containing pointer to an object, for which I want to call a function

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Request for member which is of non-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617421/request-for-member-which-is-of-non-class)

So I've created an ADT which is a singly linked list made up of nodes. These Nodes each have a pointer to an object in them called data.

```
Class Structure
{
    private:
        struct Node
        {
            Object *data;
            Node *next;
        };
        Node *head;
};
```

I am trying to call a function in the object, like this:

```
head = new Node;
head -> data = new Object();
head -> next = NULL;

cout << head -> data.print();
```

I keep getting the following error at compile.

*error: request for member 'print' in 'head->Structure::Node::data', which is of non-class type 'Object*'*

**edit: Thanks for the quick answers, amazing community. Extremely stupid mistake on my part, I feel like a fool heh :P**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a pointer, perhaps you need

```
cout << head -> data -> print();
```

? Or, if the function `print` does the printing itself, maybe just

```
head -> data -> print();
```

Answer (score 1):

For pointer types you should use `->` instead of `.` to access members or first use `*` to dereference pointer and then use `.`, so you should have `cout << head->data->print()`

Answer (score 0):

You need `cout << head->data->print()` instead of `cout << head->data.print()` you can't use the dot operator to call methods from a pointer.